# Serving https video on http pages

Tags: html, iframe, https, youtube

My website has some embedded Youtube videos where the embed URL uses http and the webpage is also served through http.  Some of my users (i.e. using Google Chrome on Windows) have told me that the video isn't playing.  However, after changing the embedded URL to serve through https, it seems to play fine (at least on Chrome).  Before I change all of the embedded urls to https, my question is whether there's ever an issue serving an embedded video through https if the webpage that it's embedded in is served through http (I know that there can be "mixed content" issues if an embedded video is http while the webpage is served through https).

The code I am using:

```
<iframe align="middle" frameborder="1" height="500" scrolling="yes" src="youtube.com/embed/video_id"; width="800"></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML snippet from your web-page?

Comment: I embed each of the videos using the code below, where I use the actual video_id that Youtube gives me in each case:<iframe align="middle" frameborder="1" height="500" scrolling="yes" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id" width="800"></iframe>

Comment: Try adding `?feature=player_embedded` immediately after `video_id`

Answer (score 1):

The issue would be the same as with any HTTPS resource - if the certificate can't be validated for whatever reason, the embedded resource won't be shown or the user will get a warning (depending on the browser implementation).

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, both the embedded resource via the iframe, as well as my webpage in which it's embedded would need to be https?

Comment: @Eric no, I just pointed at possible problem with using HTTPS by the referenced resource. Turning your web page into HTTPS won't address possible issue that I've mentioned.

Comment: OK! And supposing I get a certificate from a "reputable" company (say through Verisign) for my website: would this improve my chances that the "trouble" browsers would show the embedded video?

Comment: @Eric it's not about your page, it's about the embedded resource. If the certificate of the host where the resource resides expires, you have problems (resource not downloaded/shown) no matter how secure your web page is.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification, and it makes total sense.